# Bluetooth low energy в Chrome extension под Windows

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, bluetooth

Необходимо реализовать общение из расширения для `Chrome` с устройством по `Bluetooth Low Energy`. Проблема заключается в том, что `Web Bluetooth API` не работает в `Chrome` под `Windows`.

Вылезает ошибка:

> Web Bluetooth is not supported on this platform. For a list of supported platforms see: [link](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md#chrome)
>   Цитата

Флаг `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` **не** помогает (на страницах работает, а в расширении нет). Да и желательно решение без вмешательств от конечного юзера.

**Какие есть имплементации/способы для работы c `Bluetooth Low Energy` в `Chrome` под `Windows`?**

P.S. Находил полифил `web-bluetooth-polyfill`, но он тянет за собой `BLEServer` на C++, что мне не подходит.